# STL __stl_hash_string

Tags: c++

```
struct str_hash{
    size_t operator()(const string& str) const
    {
            unsigned long __h = 0;
            for (size_t i = 0 ; i < str.size() ; i ++)
            __h = 5*__h + str[i];
            return size_t(__h);
    }
};
```

About  the  Character  String  conversion  function in SGI STL, why use  this  expression?

```
__h = 5*__h + str[i];
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please clarify your answer and provide a more specific title to your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called *polynomial hash*. For some `x` (here `x=5`) you consider the following polynomial:

```
str[0] * x^n + str[1] * x^(n-1) + ... + str[n] * x^0
```

You can rewrite this as following:

```
(((str[0] * x) + str[1]) * x + str[2]) * x + ... ) * x + str[n]
```

It can be computed as the following

```
h = 0
h = h * x + str[0] // h = str[0]
h = h * x + str[1] // h = (str[0] * x) + str[1]
h = h * x + str[2] // h = ((str[0] * x) + str[1]) * x + str[2]
...
```

You can see that this corresponds to the line you are curious about:

```
 __h = 5*__h + str[i];
```

Polynomial hash is very crypto-unsafe and can cause nasty collisions on adversarial input, but sometimes it's fine.
Its main advantages are that it's easy to compute and that with `O(n)` preprocessing you can compute hash of any substring in `O(1)` time.
I personally find a choice of `x=5` poor (I would consider `x` to be at least greater than size of alphabet), but I don't know details of this function application.

Comment: The "computed as the following" bit is called "Horner's rule". Very handy when dealing with all sorts of polynomials.